# Python argv and cmd

Tags: python, argv

I'm trying to make a Python program that can correct exams automaticly, I have extra time and don't wanna wait for my teacher to correct them manually...
Annyways when i use python argv like this:

```
import sys

def hello(a):
    print(a)

a = sys.argv[1:]
hello(a)
```

And i want to insert a list, I can no longer insert just one variable because of the way argv works, and I can't know how long the list will be because not all tasks are the same. I'm using subprocess.check_output to return the program output after my checker runs it in a cmd window... Now if someone knows a better way to approach correcting the programs without making the students replace their input with sys.argv(if there is a better way to input arguments to a seperate python program when you run it) or can tell me how to fix the argv issue?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert a list"? Insert to where?

Comment: Are you calling *another Python script* with `subprocess`? Why not just `import` it and use the functions directly?

Comment: @BryanOakley there are 2 programs, the correcter and dummy test program i wrote above, the point is to make my correcter run the above program in windows cmd with arguements that the program needs...

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can't do that when you want to correct a whole bunch of apps

Comment: What do you mean *"correct a whole bunch of apps"*? Can't you `import` all of them? As it stands, I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to achieve or why.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am writting a program, that would take a directory full of python programs written by students, the program would take each of the students programs and run it in windows command prompt with input necesary to get desired output, but in order to do that i have to enable the extra arguements needed to input them into students programs.

Comment: And all of these programs are designed to *only* take input via `sys.argv`?  If they are sensibly structured (i.e. the parsing of the arguments is separate from their use), you could just call whatever function *uses* the arguments with whatever test values you like. Or are you trying to test the argument parsing too?

Comment: @jonrsharpe sys.argv is the only way i figured it to work, but Vincent posted a solution that works perfectly below so this is resolved now, thanks for trying to help tho :)

Comment: Glad you've sorted it. In general, you can restructure to make it easier to test these things - see e.g. https://github.com/textbook/py_wlc/blob/develop/py_wlc/data/webtag_parser.py#L220, where I've split out the parsing and usage of the arguments, then just ended with `if __name__ == "__main__": cli(parse_args(argv[1:]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Popen.communicate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead of `check_output`:

echo.py:

```
print(input())
```

test.py:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['python3', 'echo.py'], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate(input="hello!".encode())
assert out.decode().strip() == "hello!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look into [OptionParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html)